Physics of Airflow During Sneeze
I was reading the Wikipedia article about sneezing and noticed this:
"...that air ejected from the lungs is accelerated through the mouth and thus creating a low pressure point at the back of the nose. This way air is forced in through the front of the nose and the expelled mucus and contaminants are launched out the mouth."
This doesn't seem intuitively obvious to me, so I'm wondering if this is correct?
Is air forced forward out of the front of the nose during a sneeze, or is it pulled in through the front of the nose then ejected through the mouth as described above?
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneeze

Intuition is often wrong. If pondering the events surrounding a sneeze seem to contradict the Wikipedia article, a third "opinion", i.e. another science based article on sneezing and airflow (please provide a quote and a link in an edit to your post) might give you more to base your opinion on. (To be clear, Wikipedia often gets medical issues wrong.) We require evidence of prior research attempting to solve your question when posting (not just a source of a question). Thanks.
